# Twitter sharing is not working when change version 1.1

Tags: flash-builder

I have developed an air application using flex.
In that I have implemented the twitter sharing functionality.
I have changed the twitter version 1.0 to 1.1,but it is not working.
It show an below error,

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```